# How to limit Timer pending requests

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

In C# Wpf Application application i have created timer called `System.Timers.Timer`. I have set timer interval to 1 second. Inside `Timer` method i am posting data through HTTP POST to web server called `"www.posttestserver.com"`. Http post code i have used is:

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=xxx);
    string data="This is to test Http post service";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    request.Proxy = null;
    using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Flush();
        dataStream.Close();
    }
    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    response.Close();
    request.Abort();
    request = null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    myTimer .Close();
     MessageBox.Show("HttpPost:" + ex.Message);
}
```

Every thing is working fine. But the problem is
While posting when i remove the Network cable of my host (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create() is taking more time mean while my timer is running requests and timer requests are in pending and suddenly i got bunch of exceptions.
can any one help me how to solve/limit Timer pending requests.

Comment: using `Close` isn't enough, you have to set `Timer.Enabled` to false inside your `catch` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three different ways you can handle this.

The easiest way to do it is to disable the timer when you enter the callback, and then re-enable it on exit. That is:

```
void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This will prevent multiple concurrent events except in extraordinary circumstances (when the system is hugely overloaded).

You can do essentially the same thing with a lock, using the `Monitor` API. However, holding a lock for the entire time that you're doing a Web call is probably a bad idea.

You can also make the timer a one-shot so that it only ticks once and is then automatically disabled. The `Elapsed` event handler then re-enables it. To do that, you initialize your timer as you would normally, but you set `AutoReset = false;` And your event handler looks like this:

```
void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This reliably prevents multiple concurrent invocations. However, the timer doesn't tick once every second anymore. Instead, it ticks one second after the previous handler completed. So if you set the timer interval to 1 second and it takes 500 milliseconds to do the POST, then the effect will be that you make one POST request every 1.5 seconds. In most cases, this behavior is just fine unless you absolutely *must* make one request per second.

### Update

If you want to speed things up, there are several possibilities. One is to use the `lock` method I mentioned above. That will allow once-per-second ticks, which might make for slightly faster throughput. It would look like this:

```
private readonly object timerLock = new object();
void timer1_Elapsed(...)
{
    bool lockTaken;
    Monitor.TryEnter(timerLock, out lockTaken);
    if (!lockTaken) return;
    // do stuff here
    // and release the lock
    Monitor.Exit(timerLock);
}
```

Other possibilities are using a `Semaphore` to allow multiple concurrent requests, up to some fixed number. Probably 2 or 3 would be sufficient. Or you could create a request queue. Each timer tick just posts a request to a queue and a separate thread services the queue as quickly as it can. There are *always* other ways to do things, some more complicated than others, and all with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. By enabling and disabling the timer solving the problem but previously without any network failure am able to post 58 to 60 posts per minute with one second as timer interval. With this enabling and disabling the timer am able to post only 28 to 32 posts per minute. My conntent length in http post may vary from 2000 to 6000. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can do:

1. Set `myTimer.Enabled` to `false` before your try block and enable it in your `finally` block. using `Timer.Close` in the `catch` will release resources, but will only dispose the `Timer` once garbage collection is run. Use `Timer.Enabled = false` to disable it
2. Limit your request timeout to a shorter time frame using the `WebRequest.Timeout` property

Other then that, i hope your interval timeout of one second is only for testing purposes.